# Why is the value passed into the channel not being printed out by fmt.Println?

Tags: go, pointers, channel

```
func main() {
    links := []string{
        "http://google.com",
        "http://amazon.com",
        "http://golang.org",
        "http://yahoo.com",
        "http://ebay.com",
    }

    c := make(chan string)

    for _, link := range links {
        testRequest(link, c)
    }
    msg := <-c
    fmt.Println(msg)
}
func testRequest(s string, c chan string) {
    _, err := http.Get(s)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(s, "Is down presently")
        c <- "Something might be down"
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(s, "Is working perfectly")
    c <- "Working great!"
}
```

Channels are supposed to be a reference type and for some reason the function isn't passing anything to the channel because every time I run the code it prints out the first line as expected but the program doesn't stop running and also doesn't execute the `fmt.Println(channel)` so my assumption is that no value is being passed to the channel as it's supposed to be, any reason for this?

Comment: The issue here is that the program doesn't exit and does not print the value from the channel @MuffinTop

Comment: Oops, got that wrong.  The program blocks on send to channel `c`.  Communication on the unbuffered channel `c` does not proceed until a sender and receiver are ready. All sends execute before the single receive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program was stuck after the for first loop, sender try to send to channel but receiver only can receives only after the loop finished

```
//This loop will blocks until finished
for _, link := range links {
    testRequest(link, c) // Try to send, receiver can't receive
}

//Until above loop finishs, this never excutes
msg := <-c
mt.Println(msg)
```

Run the sender loop with `go` so receiver loop can excutes, but you need to prevent the main program exit until all works is complete.

```
func main() {
    links := []string{
        "http://google.com",
        "http://amazon.com",
        "http://yahoo.com",
        "http://ebay.com",
    }

    c := make(chan string)

    // This code will not blocks
    go func() {
        for _, link := range links {
            testRequest(link, c)
        }
    }()

    // Above code doesn't block, this code can excutes
    for {
        msg := <-c
        fmt.Println(msg)
    }
}

func testRequest(s string, c chan string) {
    _, err := http.Get(s)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(s, "Is down presently")
        c <- "Something might be down"
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(s, "Is working perfectly")
    c <- "Working great!"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With an unbuffered channel the write in testRequests() will block before you get to the read from the channel in main(). You're deadlocked. Generally you should get an error, normally go figures out when all goroutines are blocked. Not sure why you aren't.

You probably want to run testRequests() in a different goroutine:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    links := []string{
            "http://google.com",
            "http://amazon.com",
            "http://golang.org",
            "http://yahoo.com",
            "http://ebay.com",
    }

    c := make(chan string)

    go func() {
            for _, link := range links {
                    testRequest(link, c)
            }
            close(c)
    }()
    for msg := range c {
            fmt.Println(msg)
    }
    fmt.Println("Done handling request")
}

func testRequest(s string, c chan string) {
    _, err := http.Get(s)
    if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(s, "Is down presently")
            c <- "Something might be down"
            return
    }
    fmt.Println(s, "Is working perfectly")
    c <- "Working great!"
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/g9X1h_NNJAB

Comment: When you make an HTTP request, the HTTP transport creates a goroutine or two for housekeeping tasks (usually sleeping, but not interminably blocked), and that's enough to make the deadlock detector believe things are alright. It's nowhere near foolproof :)

Comment: Ah, that makes a ton of sense. The places I've seen it panic I didn't have any http requests going. Thanks @hobbs!